# In flutter Chip Widget, how can I move the deleteIcon to be before the label

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a chip where the close button (deleteIcon) is on the left side of the chip label (label).
how can i do that.

here is the unwantted result:

[image]

and i want to move the X to the left side of "Hagai"
like this:

[image]

```
Chip(
 deleteIcon: Icon( Icons.close, ),
 onDeleted: () {setState(() {print("bla");}); }
 label: Text("bla",),
  ),
```

An update: 
after the suggestions answers here is my new code (still dosent work):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child:

  Chip(
    label: Text(
      "bla",
    ),
    avatar: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print("bla");
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.close,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to change the direction of Chip Widget. But we can customize the Chip

```
Chip(
              label: Text(
                "bla",
              ),
              avatar: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

another solution is given by [ibhavikmakwana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786883/2196176)

**Additions**

as in the above view are visible the same as per requirement but **onTap** is not working I am working on finding the reason why it's not working.

I have created the custom **chip View**, for mean while you can use it its working fine

```
Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffDBDBDB),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    child: Wrap(
                      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                      runSpacing: 10,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("bla");
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                        Text(
                          "bla",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: @HagaiBenDavid Accept the answer, Please

Comment: hi something is still dont work for me, here is my new code, can you take a look:

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Where do you want to publish the code on SO or Google Play?

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:

      Chip(
        label: Text(
          "bla",
        ),
        avatar: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print("bla");
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.close,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: Can you Please update the above question with the requirement that you want to implement. Thnx

Comment: @HagaiBenDavid I have added the custom Chip view in the answer and its working fine and looks same as chip view

Comment: @HagaiBenDavid If it's full fill the requirement please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

Using delete in Avatar doesn't allow tap events, even with Inkwell or GestureDetector.

Use the `Directionality` widget instead

```
                 Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child:  Chip(
                         deleteIcon: Icon( Icons.close, ),
                         onDeleted: () {setState(() {print("bla");}); }
                         label: Text("bla",),
                      ),
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a `RawChip`, `Chip`,
and in `avatar` field pass your delete icon.

You can wrap your delete icon with `InkeWell` or `GestureDetector` to get the `onTap` event.

```dart
RawChip(
  label: Text(
    "bla",
  ),
  avatar: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Icon(
      Icons.close,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: this solution does not work, please check an answer before posting it